# Как заполнить ассоциативный массив

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как в PHP через foreach заполнить ассоциативный массив вида

```
Gruppa1
 qqq=>12, www=>32, eee=>33
Gruppa2
 qqq=>122, www=>3, eee=>3
Gruppa3
 qqq=>18, www=>42, eee=>37
```

с названиями Gruppa1 и qqq и тд. Я начитался в интернете способов, вот так пытался через foreach, но что то заполняется только 1 последний элемент, как будто он переписывается каждый раз, хотя k и i меняются

```
$kolmod = array($k => array($i => array($primkol=>$kolel2)))
```

Comment: Читайте __внимательней__, элементы в массив добавляются с помощью `[]`: `$kolmod[] = array()`

Comment: если массив заполняется из БД, то его можно получить сразу, без циклов

Comment: спасибо [] помогло